# How do I write a long vertical line in a group definition?

Tags: formatting, syntax

Given the following definition:

```
$ \partial K_R (z_0) = \{ z \in \mathcal{C} \vert |z-z_0| = R \} $
```

Both `\vert` and `\mid` give the same short line as | (from keyboard).
I'd like a seperator line that is longer than those to replace `\vert` in the given code line.

Comment: Try \big \vert or \Big \vert

Comment: `\big` and `\Big` will give incorrect spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `\bigm|` for that slightly larger vertical bar. That will also give it the correct spacing (relation). I have to admit that I usually use `:` here you're using `|`.

Incidentally, with vertical bars, it's worth knowing that `|` and `\vert` are functionally the same and, on their own, are treated as delimiters rather than relations. Without `\bigm`, you would want to prefer `\mid` over `|` or `\vert` in this context.

**Edited to add**: `\big` without the `m` gives ordinary spacing rather than relation spacing. You don't want that in this context. Since you show inline math mode, you probably also don't want to go to `\Bigm` (the next larger size) because that will push the line spacing a bit.

You may also want to consider using `\bigl` and `\bigr` on the braces around the set definition.

Edit: using `\bigl` and `\bigr` with `{` and `}` should be done with a forward slash:

`\big\{` and `\big\}` to avoid missing delimiter error when LaTex thinks those brackets are environmental and not a part of the macro.

Comment: I had a problem with \bigl and \bigr so I edited the answer when I found out the reason for the error. I thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use the`\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command  from `mathtools` to obtain the set-builder notation with a single `\set` command.The starred version adds an implicit `\left \right` pair. Other than this, it can take an optional argument (from the `\big, \Big, \bigg,\Bigg`  list), which adds an implicit `\bigl \bigr, \Bigl \Bigr, &c.` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

    \[ \partial K_R (z_0) = \set[\big]{ z \in \mathcal{C} ; |z-z_0| = R} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$ \partial K_R (z_0) = \bigl\{\, z \in \mathcal{C} \mathrel{\big\vert} |z-z_0| = R \,\bigr\} $`